# ASP.NET page not inheriting from base page

Tags: c#, asp.net, inheritance, master-pages

I have implemented a base page in my ASP.NET application. In this class I have an object which I want to be available to all other pages in my application.

Here is my base page implementation...

```
using System;
using System.Web;

public class MyBasePage : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected User ActiveUser;

    public MyBasePage()
    {
          ActiveUser = new User();
    }
}
```

My problem is I have made a page inherit from this class but the ActiveUser object is not visible to it. Here is the way I've inherited it.

```
public partial class Suppliers_Default : MyBasePage
{
}
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: It looks right.  When you say it is not visible, are you getting a build error?

Comment: protected User ActiveUser;  then ActiveUser = new User(); but u are using  ActiveUser = new ActiveUser();

Comment: The IntelliSense suggestions doesn't display it as an option, so I can't interact with the object.

Comment: Is `ActiveUser` a derived class of `User`? If that is not a typo, then post the code for `ActiveUser` class.

Comment: My apologies @Ratna, I have corrected the line "ActiveUser = new User();" line, but it's still not showing.

Comment: Also make sure you have placed your MyBasePage class in app_code folder.

Comment: MyBasePage is located in the App_Code folder.

Comment: yours code is corrects, tell about the exact error you are getting. If you arent getting any errors then intellisence is the culprit, just find out are you able to compile it or not?

Comment: I restarted VS and it worked! Thanks people.

Answer (score 4):

Check if your .cs file it has "Build Action" property set to "Compile".

> > Right click / Properties / Build Action

Comment: I had recently converted a Web Site project to a Web Application project and the BasePage class had it's build action set to Content weirdly - it came from App_Code in the old project. Anyway, setting it to Compile sorted it out so thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
public partial class Suppliers_Default : MyBasePage
{
public Suppliers_Default:base(){}
}
```

or

```
public class MyBasePage : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected User ActiveUser {get;set;};

    public MyBasePage()
    {
          ActiveUser = new User();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you have one class MyBasePage and other User Class

```
using System;
using System.Web;

public class MyBasePage : System.Web.UI.Page
{
   protected User ActiveUser;

   public MyBasePage()
   {
       ActiveUser = new User();
   }
}
```

if you want to access property/method you can use following two ways

Solution 1

```
public partial class Suppliers_Default : MyBasePage
 {
   // Using Object Of MyBasePage / parent class 
   MyBasePage objMyBP = new MyBasePage();
   objMyBP.ActiveUser.Methodname();
 }
```

Solution 2

```
public partial class Suppliers_Default : MyBasePage
 {
   //Using Base Keyword
   Base.ActiveUser.Methodname();    // here Methodname() is from User class

 }
```

*you can also access property same as method